# Re-generate same debug.keystore

Tags: android, android-keystore

I had one app installed on my device using debug.keystore which has database store under data dictionary.

Because of some issue of window 7 i have to format it and i lost debug.keystore.

Now I want to update the app but error is "Re-installation failed due to different application signatures".

My purpose is i want the database which is stored in data directory.

Try this but not worked :

```
String currentDBPath = "/data/data/com.myapp/databases/myappdatabase.sqlite";
String backupDBPath = "/sdcard/myappdatabase.sqlite";
try {
    DatabaseExtractor.extractFromDevice(currentDBPath, backupDBPath);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because of some issue of window 7 i have to format it and i lost debug.keystore.

Restore your `debug.keystore` from your PC backup. If you do not maintain backups of your development machine, please stop all software development until you do.

> My purpose is i want the database which is stored in data directory.

Either restore your `debug.keystore` from a backup, or root your phone (so you can gain access to this directory), or you will have no means of accessing this data.

Comment: can i make my own debug.keystore for future use?

Comment: @BipinVayalu: Using the development tools, without an existing `debug.keystore`, will create one for you, that is good for a year. If you are planning on using this app for longer than that, please create a production keystore and use that for the app you use on your phone, rather than the debug one.

Comment: I think i make one production certificate with 25 years named debug.keystore and put it in .android folder. is this works for me?

Comment: @BipinVayalu: There used to be a restriction that the `debug.keystore` had a maximum lifespan of 1 year. I have not seen any reference to this in quite some time, though, so it is possible they have lifted this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Remove previous version of your app and install new one. To regenerate debug.keystore: delete your debug certificate under  the directory `%USERPROFILE%/.android`on Windows.
The Eclipse plugin should then generate a new certificate when you next try to build a debug package. You may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work, but please don't blame me if you lose your database:

```
adb uninstall -k <package>
```

`-k` should keep your data directory.

Then install the new app version signed with your new debug key.